# Very bad flex load time, but only non Chrome browsers

Tags: flash, apache-flex, firefox, google-chrome, flash-builder

My flex application has a very bad load time (approx 5 to 8 wasted seconds) but only for FF and IE, Chrome appears fine.

I've determined there is some kind of useless idle time before the application's initalization event fires.  This is not just my development box, it happens everywhere.   It is consistent across Flash version, OS and browser versions too.  I've tried multiple.   Chrome consistenly works very fast, IE and FF have this strange lag.

However locally, whether via localhost or remote IP, it doesn't have this issue.  I'm sure you'll think it is the download time, but my SWF is very small (400K) and I've purposely made external images that are very small.   I also prefetch the images via JavaScript, and firebug reports the the cache is used later.  The download size can't really justify the wait time.  Not to mention, why is it so much faster in chrome?  Is chrome really that fast downloading images and SWF files?

Also, minimal JavaScript is called from Flex, and I've more or less ruled out that is the issue.  So it isn't Chrome's super fast handling of JavaScript.

I don't see any large load times with Firebug.   I see JavaScript excute in the browser inline during a page load, but then the appliation init within the SWF doesn't fire for about 5 to 8 seconds later.

I don't see why flash on Chrome is so much faster, nor what could be taking so long for Flash to kick in.

EDIT: Tried the Flex Profiler, but memory usage spikes AFTER the bad load time.  Otherwise, I don't know enough or see enough to recognize a problem with it.

Comment: Is this on all computers or just one that you're benchmarking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out (for whatever reason) these browser are very slow if you use CSS to make the SWF invisible.  Which I was doing while the page/Flash loaded.

Thanks for the suggestions all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the whole functionality and see if the problem persists. If not, then start progressively uncommenting things until you get to the part that produces the problem. If you can't figure out why that part is having the undesirable effects, post a new question with specifics.

Comment: I can't really do that.  Little to no JavaScript executes to comment out.  The app init method is the first thing that fires in ActionScript.   There really isn't anything to comment out or remove.  I've tried that with the image size, didn't help.

Comment: @Maximegalon, well, comment the whole init method and see if the problem's still there. If not, then uncomment things inside the init method until you get to the one that makes the problem happen.

Comment: I can try to kill off random stuff, but according to the output the problem is BEFORE init fires.  All my init does is create the main UI and establish logging.   The first thing the init function does is give me the system time, which I then determine took for ever for it to fire.

Comment: @Maximegalon, I see, so the problem is happening even before any part of your code gets to execute.

Comment: Correct, or at least that is the indication.   Inline browser JavaScript runs, then ActionScript appears to run 5 to 8 seconds later.  But only for non Chrome.   So either Chrome is super awesome at sending bits of SWF and IMGs faster, or Flash is hosed in some way.  I check all these load times with standard flex and firebug console output.

Comment: If this was a 1 or 2 second thing, I'd chalk it up to better downloads.  But Chrome is soooooo much faster at kicking off the SWF/Flash execution.

Comment: Watch in Charles Proxy and see what's being called, when.  I would suspect an RSL issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the debug Flash Player installed in FF and IE.  Chrome has its own bundled release Flash Player.  This is normal behavior, and nice because you can use Chrome to see what your users will see, Firefox to debug, and IE to... help @mcandre QA his HTML5 websites?

Answer (score -3):

Use HTML5 instead. Flash is a dinosaur.

Comment: Fair enough, but you'd have to convince my boss to switch.

Comment: HTML5's got its own issues. It's not a solid or mature application development platform. It's nice for websites, but business logic rich applications? I don't think so.

Comment: @JeffN825 - Exactly, also we're using 3rd party functionality that basically no one has really created in HTML 5 (yet)